# Android resource string in text view

Tags: c#, android, string, visual-studio, xamarin

I have the following string file with descriptions I use on captions/labels. Now I want to add a value to the description and show it in a textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="labelTimeScore">Time: </string>
</resources>
```

I tried:
    txtTimeScore.Text = Resource.String.labelTimeScore + "00:10:33";

Expected this output:
"Time: 00:10:33"

But all I get is numbers. Do I need to string format the value?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: You are doing in wrong way call  do it proper Like context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.KeyfortheString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

since you are in a adapter you will have to use the context:

```
context.getString(Resource.string.lblTimeScore);
```

Comment: The "R" is just the problem. It is not recognized in the code. Perhaps because the code is used within my ListViewAdapter class? Can I get to the R through the context?

Comment: @BerendOtten Can you try cleaning the project?

Comment: Where are you calling it in the `ListViewAdapter` class?

Comment: public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null)
    {
        row = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.score_row, null, false);
    }

    //getString(R.String.lblTimeScore);

    txtTimeScore.Text = R.String.lblTimeScore + scoreList.ScoreData[position].time_score.ToString();
    return row;
    }

Comment: Thanks Derek! Though the ever troublesome "R" is replaced by "Resource" and now the desciptions are shown.

Comment: @BerendOtten Perfect, I updated my answer to show the correct `Resource`

Comment: @BerendOtten if you don't mind marking this as correct, then if future users have the same issue. they will know what fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing in wrong way,
You can not directly get the string from resource it will return the resource Id (a integer)instead  of string. To get the string value write like this.

```
txtTimeScore.Text=Resources.GetString(Resource.String.labelTimeScore)+"00:10:33";
```